# Stop jquery function from .bind and .MouseUp

Tags: javascript, function

Have a jquery where "displayInput" display some hidden input controls, and by clicking outside or pressing enter or escape, back to it hidden state..

.bind and .mouseup only work as soon I run displayInputs, that's ok.. the problem is both still fire to the console.log and I cant find a way to stop them.

```
function displayInputs(ID){
     //Show Inputs

     $(document).bind('keypress', function(e){
          if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 27){ // escape or enter key
               //Hide Inputs
               console.log('still alive');
               return false;
          }
     });

     // Outside click action
     $(document).mouseup(function(e){
          //Hide Inputs
          console.log('still alive');
          return false;
     }
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/583nogqa/1/)

$(document).off(); seems it works but kill other scripts..

Comment: Pass a reference to the function you want to remove to `$(document).off()` ?

Comment: Hooo... good point.. seems $(document).off('keypress'); is the solution...

Comment: @Musikdoktor do you want to stop key press once it is pressed? What about $(document).unbind('keypress') ?

Comment: Yes. on the Fiddle, click outside the text.. nothing happens.. now click on the text.. and then click back outside you can see the log is working but as much you click outside the script still running.. and i want to fire once.. and loop again if i press the text..  the problem is how to stop the mouseup event.. but seems Felix Kling gave a good point.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that you are assigning the keypress and mouseup to the document. In the functions you should check which was clicked. Check out this (escape not working here...):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        //Show Inputs
        $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 27) { // escape or enter key
                //Hide Inputs
                console.log('keypress');

            }
        });

        // Outside click action
        $(document).click(function(e) {
            //Hide Inputs
            if (e.target.id === "input") {
                console.log("click on input");
            } else {
            console.log('clicked outside');
            }
        });
    })
```

```css
        body {
            height: 100%;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        
        #input {
            background-color: #cecece;
            padding: 15px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="input">Click Here fires DisplayInput</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, The problem is once i fire the function, i cant stop the mouse event.. 
but as i mentioned, $(document).off('keypress'); and $(document).off('mouseup'); seems to be the solution.